# How to put two divs on same line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've 2 divs. I'm using Bootstrap.

I want to have the text and start aligned and close to eachother.

Rightnow, I was playing with `col-md-x` but not getting what I need:

Expected:

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/yLLjLjr

Comment: Why are you separating them in columns if they are supposed to be right next to each other? That seems like your main problem, and then vertical alignment. Seems like you should not be using col-md-x in this case, that is for using the 12-column grid and your header is always going to take up 1/3 of the space in the row, your stars container will always be 2/3 of the space.

Comment: Worth checking out docs for bootstrap flex stuff - or make your elements inline-block elements and use vertical-alignment. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this [Jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/m52fsh0k/2/). To fix this issue I have used only three bootstrap classes `.d-flex`, `.align-items-center` and `.d-inline-block`.
It is not a best practice, applying `.row` and `.col` classes everywhere in your layout. You need to understand the right place for their application.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <h2 id="product-name" class="">Stickers troquelados</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <span class="">
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                            <!-- <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star-half-alt"></i></a> -->
                            858 comentarios
                    </span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I works, but the stars and "858 comentarios" are exactly at the same level. In the expected image the stars and "858 comentarios" are a little higher, so they end up in the center, horizontally alligened with "Stickers Troquelados".

Comment: @OmarGonzales, that mentioned vertical align issue is fixed and updated my answer. You can check it now. Thanks.

Comment: would you mention what changes did you do?

Comment: @OmarGonzales, I added bootstrap classes .d-flex, .align-items-center and .d-inline-block for the outer wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding the div's that you want to align inline like below

```
<div class="d-flex">
 <div class="d-inline-block"> Your div 1 </div>
 <div class="d-inline-block"> Your div 2 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of adding css styles, if you are using bootstrap, as bootstrap works completely on grid system you need to adjust the columns and rows as per your convenience.

I have updated your code just have a look on it, and tell me if anything you want to make change in the code

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-inline-block">
                <h2 id="product-name" class="">Stickers troquelados</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 pt-2">
                             <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="gold-star fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                            <!-- <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star"></i></a>
                            <a class=""><i class="gold-star fas fa-star-half-alt"></i></a> -->
                            858 comentarios
            </div>
    </div>
```

I am also adding codeSandbox link so you can understand more concisely.

Link :- [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-shirley-p8k9c?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thats why I have given you codeSandbox link as the page is not responsive so will see the sentence broken, In codeSandbox just Expand the browser of codeSandbox

Answer (score -1):

Use Flexbox,

```
<div class="row-div">
  <div>Stickers troquelados</div>
  <div>***** 858 Comments</div>
</div>
```

css,

```
.row-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* Having some margin to make the two divs some distance */
.row-div>div {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Agreed this is trivial but OP is using bootstrap which uses flexbox so probably not right to add additional custom CSS. OP should learn how to use the framework they're currently using IMO which absolutely provides this.